# How do I enable Visual Studio 2010 to break when a first chance exception happens?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, first-chance-exception

I was reading Stack Overflow question *[How can I set Visual Studio to show a stack trace for first chance exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195498)* regarding debugging first chance exceptions on Visual Studio 2010, and I am not able to find this option.

How can I enable Visual Studio 2010 to break exactly when a first chance exception happens?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You may want to check the Debug menu in Visual Studio 2010. In there you will find the Exception submenu, in where you can select which type of exception you want Visual Studio to stop.

> **Setting the debugger to break when an exception is thrown**
>
> The debugger can break execution at the point where an exception is
>   thrown, giving you a chance to examine the exception before a handler
>   is invoked.
>
> In the Exception Settings window, expand the node for a category of
>   exceptions (for example, Common Language Runtime Exceptions, meaning
>   .NET exceptions), and select the check box for a specific exception
>   within that category (for example System.AccessViolationException).
>   You can also select an entire category of exceptions.
>
> [image]
>
> If you check a given exception, debugger execution will break wherever
>   the exception is thrown, regardless of whether it is handled or
>   unhandled. At this point the exception is called a first chance
>   exception.

See *[How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)* for more info.

Answer (score 30):

**In Visual Studio to enable 1st chance exceptions we can open the exceptions window and check the throw CLR Exception chekbox.**

On the debug menu select exceptions. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)

There is a Common Language Runtime Exception Thown checkbox that we can check; then click OK.

The screen show below is from VS2012:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I miss this dialog