# Visual Studio Exception Settings Window - possible to show only first Exception?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Exception settings window is helpful in debugging - yet sometimes the same exception is shown in multiple places when debugging - and it is annoying to press F5 in those exceptions when I need to go to another targeted exception.

This is especially troublesome when the exception thrown is a generic exception (e.g. object instance null) thus I cannot ignore that exception. And it takes a long time to wait for the next exception rethrow. If I just press hold F5 - it could get out out of the exception warnings and if it comes back to the web page it refreshes the page which is also bothersome.

Is there any way with VS Settings, extensions (e.g. resharper etc), or some other wizardry that we could ask the Exception settings window only to show exception in the very first time it appeared (first chance exception etc) that could allow us to catch every exception the first time it appeared? Technically this could be checked with some stack trace matching.

Answer (score 1):

> > **Is there any way with VS Settings, extensions (e.g. resharper etc), or some other wizardry that we could ask the Exception settings window only to show exception in the very first time it appeared (first chance exception etc) that could allow us to catch every exception the first time it appeared? Technically this could be checked with some stack trace matching.**

What I know is that it could capture the first chance exception using the Exception setting windows, but not only this kind of exceptions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/

Or you really know that what the exception is firstly, and then just enable the Exception option like this case:

[How do I enable Visual Studio 2010 to break when a first chance exception happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218249/how-do-i-enable-visual-studio-2010-to-break-when-a-first-chance-exception-happen)

But I think it was not the way you want to use, because we don't know what the exception is before we debugging the app.

I also help you submit a feature request to the product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32391226-visual-studio-exception-settings-window-possible

If possible, you could add your comment and vote this user voice.

Comment: Thanks added the comment there.