# ASP.NET throwing generic 500 Error in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am running an ASP.NET application and my browser just sends a http 500 error on my browser.

The application is hosted in IIS. It is running in "Classic" app pool.

There is no information available in "Output window".

No much information in browser console.

However it is hitting `Global.asax` and the following methods:

```
Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I inspect sender I see the following error:

> Session : ((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
>
> Response:
> Headers : `((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'`

```
Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Even though there is `Application_Error()`, it is not getting hit.

No further breakpoints in code getting executed.

How can I debug further to see what the error is?

Comment: In your OWIN Startup code, add a listener to `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException`. 
Also, build a `DEBUG` build, deploy that, then attach VS to `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: @Dai , attaching vs to w3wp.exe is done. That's how the control is coming to global.asax file

Comment: I don't know what you meant by that.

Comment: I am successfully able to attach vs to w3wp.exe and hit the global.asax events in debug mode .

Comment: Ensure you have "Just my code" **disabled** - and also configure VS to break-on-first-chance-exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218249/how-do-i-enable-visual-studio-2010-to-break-when-a-first-chance-exception-happen

Comment: Core was developed so same source code would run on Windows, Linux, Mac. Errors like yours where Platform not Supported is due to your target being Net (not Core) where the OS is not supporting the method.  The only way of fixing is to use a different library (or method) that will work on the OS.  Or change target to Core where you may need to make other change in the source code.

Comment: IIS is windows and error Platform not supported is odd.  I suspect it has to do with HTTPS encryption where IIS is very old and does not support the newer encryption algorithms that is used with TLS.

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.